# illegal configuration error xcode6, can I disable it?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode6, ios-autolayout

I have a number of projects which support iOs5.  When adding a launch.xib file I have an error

```
error: Illegal Configuration: Auto Layout on iOS Versions prior to 6.0
```

now everything works fine, I can build and run to my old devices, they don't support the launch.xib file obviously, so they're falling back to the asset catalog for an image just as it ever was, they do not try to load the xib, therefore they don't throw any 'wtf is NSAutolayoutConstraint' type exception.. but the nib being there saves me worrying about the new iPhone6 sizes for start images, as well as any future screen sizes.

But this red **!** up top is driving me crazy !!  I'm not accustomed to ignoring them, nor to having one on my screen yet having my project happily build and run on all targets...  Can anybody please give me a clue how to disable a specific error message in xcode6 (which I view as pointless) .   Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Auto Layout in Storyboard settings. Click `Main.storyboard` on the left, then in right panel 1st Tab, turn off "Auto Layout" (turn off Size Classes of Xcode 6 as well).

Of course, I would recommend you not to support iOS 5 anymore, as Apple has discontinued its support already.

Comment: thank you.  This is very obvious, and the error will go away.  If I have any other nibs in these projects (I don't) I would obviously have to do that.
However I do want the benefit of auto layout for my launch nib, and its working just great.  I just want a way to silence this error message because its distracting me.   Thank you but you don't answer my question.  I do appreciate it :)

Comment: No you can't. Auto Layout is the feature starting from iOS 6. You have to manually calculate the layout via programming.

Comment: thanks, I do appreciate your efforts and certainly have no desire to be disrespectful...
BUT
the question IS NOT 'how do I make autoLayout work in iOs5'..
the question is 'how do I disable a specific error message in xCode' thanks mate.

these are 4 apps which are on the App Store already.  I will happily drop iOs5 support anytime I need to.  But I do not yet need to, and my iPad1 and 3Gs make great 'entry level' test platforms.  These projects all build and run just fine even to iOs5.  I just want to be rid of the red exclamation point.  thanks mate

Comment: Understand, but you can't.